# Change service credentials using ServiceController

Tags: c#, windows, wmi, servicecontroller

Is there a way to do this, but instead of using WMI which is not currently working in my environment, using ServiceController Class.

```
using (ManagementObject service = new ManagementObject(new ManagementPath(objPath)))
                {
                    object[] wmiParams = new object[11];
                    wmiParams[6] = _username;
                    wmiParams[7] = _password;
                    service.InvokeMethod("Change", wmiParams);
                    Thread.Sleep(2000);
                    //check if new credentials in order
                    //Console.WriteLine("Service credentials changed");
                }
```

Thanks!

Comment: @A_Nablsi I saw that you might know how to do this. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The `ServiceController` class doesn't let you change service credentials. If WMI isn't an option, you can P/Invoke [`ChangeServiceConfig`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681987.aspx) instead. You can find a C# example here:

[Changing Log On Credentials of Windows Services](https://msmvps.com/blogs/siva/archive/2007/04/19/changing-log-on-credentials-of-windows-service.aspx)

Comment: link is dead :( Maybe this is it? https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/33428/How-to-Change-User-Credentials-of-Windows-Services