# Set windows service password without restart

Tags: sql, .net, service, passwords, restart

I am trying to set a password to a windows service without having to restart the service.  If you change it in service manager it will tell you that it won't take effect until you restart.

SQL Configuration Manager lets you set the pwd (If that's all your changing) without restarting the service.  I would like to do this in code, for more than just the SQL Services.

(I KNOW HOW TO SET A PWD), I need help doing it without forcing a restart like SSCM.

Comment: you can use WMI classes or PInvoke ChangeServiceConfig. Helen answered 2,5 years ago here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24455668/change-service-credentials-using-servicecontroller, thanks not received  :-)

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but hers also requires a reboot, yes you can change it without restarting but in a few days it will fail, SQL Configuration Manager, it will never fail.  It doesn't need to restart.  Here is the bottom of the article Helen pointed to: The service should
 be restarted for the new settings to take effect – what this means is that if the
 password you supplied for the user name is incorrect, for example, you will not
 know this until the service is restarted!